# Upper bound of a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

Suppose I have a form $|X^TBY|$ where $X \in R^n, Y \in R^m$ and $B \in R^{n \times m}$ is a matrix whose elements are bounded. Is there an upper bound for the whole expression of the form $|X^TBY|\le \lambda ||X||||Y||$?

Comment: What is the norm?

Comment: @Eff It's the euclidean norm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$|X^TBY| \leq \|X\|\|BY\|$. Also, $\|BY\| \leq \|B\|\|Y\|$, where $\|B\|$ is the Euclidean operator norm of $B$ (i.e., the largest singular value of $B$). So together this gives $$|X^TBY| \leq \|B\|\|X\|\|Y\|.$$